# Selenium Java- Drop down selection where Style- display is none

Tags: java, selenium

When I try to select a drop down with Style display: none;

option 1:

```
WebElement sysDropDown = driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlFeedStatus")); 

Select sDropdown = new Select(sysDropDown); 
sDropdown.selectByVisibleText("01 - Quarantined");
```

The above code renders error:

> element not interactable: Element is not currently visible and may not
>   be manipulated

Option 2:

```
WebElement hiddenWebElement =driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@name='ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlFeedStatus']"));

((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click()",hiddenWebElement);
```

Option2 recognizes the drop down but unable to select an item from the drop down.

Any help would be appreciated.

Tried few options i see in the site but didtn't help much

Answer (score 0):

You could try altering the `style` attribute using Javascript, as such:

```
hiddenWebElement = driver.findElement(
    By.xpath("//select[@name='ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlFeedStatus']")); 

((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(
    "arguments[0].style.display = 'block';", hiddenWebElement);
```

After that, you can try a Javascript click or regular click.

Answer (score 0):

Could you right click -> Inspect and see if it is really a dropdown? If drop down is visible and still getting this error, it might not an html dropdown. It may look like one but can only confirm if you inspect or look at code.

If element is an html drop down, use the following code to see if it works:

```
    WebElement sysDropDown = driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlFeedStatus")); 
    Coordinates coordinate = ((Locatable) sysDropDown).getCoordinates();
    coordinate.onPage();
    coordinate.inViewPort();

    Select sDropdown = new Select(sysDropDown); 
    sDropdown.selectByVisibleText("01 - Quarantined");
```

Comment: i think you are right...doesn't look like html drop down...it has search built in to the drop down

Comment: If you resolve Locatable (missing depdency), you can still try it. Alternative you can supply text to search input and then select the drop down.